# How exactly batch work in cql

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax, cql3, datastax-java-driver

I was going through datastax `CQL Java Driver 2.1` driver document and also through CQL 2.X reference pdf:

In  CQL reference pdf:

```
Batches are atomic by default. In the context of a Cassandra batch operation, 
atomic means that if any of the batch succeeds, all of it will.
```

In CQL java driver pdf:

```
Batch operations
The BATCH statement combines multiple data modification statements (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) into
a single logical operation which is sent to the server in a single request. Also batching together multiple
operations ensures these are executed in an atomic way: either all succeed or none.
```

So what i understood from first, that a batch is success even if a single query inside batch is sucess.

from second i understood that a batch is failed even if a single query inside batch fails

So what is the exact thing ?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28348717/how-do-atomic-batches-work-in-cassandra

Comment: If i do execute two INSERT on different table inside a BATCH, will that be really a BATCH execution?

Comment: In Cassandra terms, yes. Both inserts will be executed together in one batch.

Comment: can you provide links for both of these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of **logged** batches is atomicity. If any one query in the batch fails the entire batch will fail and if the batch succeeds, that means every query in the batch succeeded.

`either all succeed or none` is accurate.

Comment: So if i use insert,delete or update on `two different table` within a batch then also it will be like that?