# Update row in multiple table in Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra

I am using cassandra 2.x version and have a requirement to insert/update one row to multiple tables. all tables have different primary key. How can I add multiple assignments to update and more than 1 table name to `QueryBuilder`.  Using datastax driver. Any pointer would be helpful.

Comment: Does a `batch` statement fulfill your need? If you are unfamiliar with batch statements see this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28348717/how-do-atomic-batches-work-in-cassandra/28348718#28348718) on atomicity in batch statements.

Comment: I am familiar with Batch, but not sure how can I prepare BatchStatement with multiple tables.

Comment: Looking at this again, is atomicity required? Otherwise you would simply create multiple prepared statements and execute each one after the event.

Comment: Yeah. I need atomicity and I am using queryBuilder

Answer (score 1):

Someone else asked [how to batch update multiple tables](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!topic/csharp-driver-user/9-ZA2dVHkEs) on the google group. They [referred to a C# driver example](https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver#batching-statements) of multiple table updating. The principle applies to Java and I have copied the relevant `BatchStatement` method from the [cassandra java driver](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/2.1/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/BatchStatement.java).

Relevant code quoted from Java driver below:

```
/**
     * Adds a new statement to this batch.
     * <p/>
     * Note that {@code statement} can be any {@code Statement}. It is allowed to mix
     * {@code RegularStatement} and {@code BoundStatement} in the same
     * {@code BatchStatement} in particular. Adding another {@code BatchStatement}
     * is also allowed for convenience and is equivalent to adding all the {@code Statement}
     * contained in that other {@code BatchStatement}.
     * <p/>
     * When adding a {@code BoundStatement}, all of its values must be set, otherwise an
     * {@code IllegalStateException} will be thrown when submitting the batch statement.
     * See {@link BoundStatement} for more details, in particular how to handle {@code null}
     * values.
     * <p/>
     * Please note that the options of the added Statement (all those defined directly by the
     * {@link Statement} class: consistency level, fetch size, tracing, ...) will be ignored
     * for the purpose of the execution of the Batch. Instead, the options used are the one
     * of this {@code BatchStatement} object.
     *
     * @param statement the new statement to add.
     * @return this batch statement.
     * @throws IllegalStateException if adding the new statement means that this
     *                               {@code BatchStatement} has more than 65536 statements (since this is the maximum number
     *                               of statements for a BatchStatement allowed by the underlying protocol).
     */
    public BatchStatement add(Statement statement) {

        // We handle BatchStatement here (rather than in getIdAndValues) as it make it slightly
        // easier to avoid endless loop if the use mistakenly pass a batch that depends on this
        // object (or this directly).
        if (statement instanceof BatchStatement) {
            for (Statement subStatements : ((BatchStatement) statement).statements) {
                add(subStatements);
            }
        } else {
            if (statements.size() >= 0xFFFF)
                throw new IllegalStateException("Batch statement cannot contain more than " + 0xFFFF + " statements.");
            statements.add(statement);
        }
        return this;
    }
```

Basic idea is create a variable for each table update and add each of the variables to the `BatchStatement` function.

Comment: This particular example is for csharp, I am using java driver.