# What are the similarities and differences between a BATCH statement in Cassandra and a Transaction in SQL?

Tags: cassandra, transactions, atomic, acid

The goal of a Cassandra [Batch](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/batch_r.html) statement is to [group](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useBatch.html) statements on the one partition [together](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useBatchGoodExample.html) in a single [atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)) operation (all pass or fail [together](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28348718/15441)).

This is quite similar to how an [SQL Transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction#In_SQL) works.

To me it seems the main difference is that with an SQL Transaction, you get an [ACID consistency guarantee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_(database_systems)#As_an_ACID_guarantee) at the end of it, which you don't necessarily get with a Cassandra Batch statement.

My question is: **What are the similarities and differences between a BATCH statement in Cassandra and a Transaction in SQL?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cassandra only support Atomicity and Isolation at the partition level**

> Cassandra does not use RDBMS ACID transactions with rollback or locking mechanisms, but instead offers atomic, isolated, and durable transactions with eventual/tunable consistency that lets the user decide how strong or eventual they want each transaction’s consistency to be.
>
> As a non-relational database, Cassandra does not support joins or foreign keys, and consequently does not offer consistency in the ACID sense

Read More : http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlTransactionsDiffer.html

Answer (score 1):

The answer is already in your question: **one partition**

Which means, that C*'s batch is not an universal tool to maintain consistency and atomicity like transactions in RDBMS. It is not possible to maintain strict atomicity and consistency across nodes with C* batches, so in a busines usecase set, there are many "transactions" what could be / should be atomic, but you can not use C* batch to ensure that, because the data included those "transactions" are split on multiple nodes.